# Check whether all pixels in a cropped image have a specific color (OpenCV/Python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    tag = frame[235:245, 315:325]
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_red = np.array([20, 20, 50])
    upper_red = np.array([255, 255, 130])
    
    for i in range (235,245):
        for j in range (315,325):
                if cv2.inRange(tag[i][j],lower_red,upper_red):
                    break
        
        cv2.imshow('image',frame)
    
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break
        
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i want to check my middle 100 pixels in my 480,640 camera to see if they all fall in a certain color range and if they do to end the program but i cant find i way to compare the values of the middle 100 pixels with the values that i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problems with your approach:

**1. Improper variable handling**: You are cropping your image to `tag` before converting to HSV color space

**2. Wrong usage of `cv2.inRange()`**: The function returns a binary image of values either `0` or `255`.

- `0` -> if the pixels **do not** fall in range
- `255` -> if the pixels fall in range

Thumb rule: **Avoid using `for` loops**

---

#### Solution:

Since `cv2.inRange()` returns a binary image, just find the average of the pixel values within the cropped image. If the average is `255` (all the pixels are white and within the color range) -> break!

---

You can alter your code using the following snippet:

```
ret, frame = cap.read()

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_red = np.array([20, 20, 50])
upper_red = np.array([255, 255, 130])

tag = hsv[235:245, 315:325]
mask = cv2.inRange(tag, lower_red, upper_red)

if np.mean(mask) == 255:
    print("All the pixels are within the color range")
    break
```